# JHipster Generator Customizations (IDE config)

Tags: ejs, jhipster

I want to make some frontend changes to the JHipster Generator v7.9.3. Actually I have already made some changes in the entity-client subgenerator. For example, in generators\entity-client\templates\angular\src\main\webapp\entities\update\entity-management-update.component.html.ejs and generators\entity-client\templates\angular\src\main\webapp\entities\update\entity-management-update.component.ts.ejs).

However, it's quite a pain because I don't have any experience working with EJS templates. First, I would be interested in how to configure my IDE (Intellij or VSCode) so that auto-formatting works and no syntax errors are detected by the IDE. On the other hand I would be interested if there is any documentation available.
I wanted to do generator customizations first and if they work as desired, write them to a blueprint. However, to keep it simple I would like to just customize the templates first.

I am grateful for any tips.